# Get an element height number

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wanna get the height of the Custom Header I've made to use it on the padding of the scroll view. I've tried something but is laggy and also not working. If u have any ideas on how to make a custom header that changes height based on the element's I have it would be appreciated :)

I used a ZStack since I dont know any better way to reproduce what I want (just a custom header that changes based on what my API response is, and a List that scrolls

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack (alignment: .top) {
                GeometryReader { gr in
                    VStack (spacing: 24) {
                        HStack (spacing: 14) {
                            balunImage
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(height: 25)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Image(systemName: "clock")
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        }.padding(.horizontal)
                        
                        ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                                HStack (spacing: 0) {
                                    ForEach(-6...6, id: \.self) { dayOffset in
                                        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: dayOffset, to: Date()) ?? Date()
                                        let dateString = self.formatterString(for: dayOffset, with: date)
                                        
                                        Text(dateString)
                                            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                                            .foregroundColor(dayOffset == selectedDayIndex ? Color.textAccent : Color.gray)
                                            .background(alignment: .bottom, content: {
                                                if dayOffset == selectedDayIndex {
                                                    Capsule()
                                                        .fill(Color.textAccent)
                                                        .frame(height: 3)
                                                        .padding(.horizontal, 14)
                                                        .offset(y: 15)
                                                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "ACTIVEDAY", in: namespace)
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                            .onTapGesture {
                                                func stringFromDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
                                                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                                                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
                                                    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                                                }
                                                
                                                let formattedDateString = stringFromDate(date)
                                                print(formattedDateString)
                                                dataViewModel.fetchData(forDate: formattedDateString)
                                                
                                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                                                    scrollView.scrollTo(dayOffset, anchor: .center)
                                                    self.selectedDayIndex = dayOffset
                                                }
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                                .onAppear {
                                    scrollView.scrollTo(selectedDayIndex, anchor: .center)
                                }
                                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                            }.padding(.bottom, 0)
                        }
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.textAccent)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    .padding(.bottom, 13)
                    .offset(y: max(0, -gr.frame(in: .global).origin.y + 60))
                    .background(Color.bgSecondaryAccent)
                    .background(
                        GeometryReader { headerGeometry in
                            Color.clear
                                .onAppear {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                                        headerHeight = headerGeometry.size.height // <--- Here I get the height
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    )
                }
                
                List {
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                        LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                            ForEach(dataViewModel.data?.leagues ?? [], id: \.id) { league in
                                VStack {
                                    leagueHeader(league: league)
                                    ForEach(league.matches, id: \.id) { match in
                                        matchRow(match: match)
                                    }
                                }
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.textAccent)
                                .background(Color.bgSecondaryAccent)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                            }
                        }.padding(10)
                    }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .background(Color.bgAccent)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                }
                .padding(.top, headerHeight) // <--- Here I use the height
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                .onAppear { UIRefreshControl.appearance().tintColor = .gray }
                .refreshable { dataViewModel.fetchData() }
                .onAppear {
                    UIRefreshControl.appearance().tintColor = .gray
                    dataViewModel.fetchData()
                    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true) { _ in
                        dataViewModel.fetchData()
                    }
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    timer?.invalidate()
                    timer = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It looks like your `ZStack` contains your "header" (consisting of a `VStack` at top level) and a `List`. Then you are applying top padding to the `List`, so that it is below the header. So why not just use a `VStack` instead of a `ZStack`?

Comment: Please, provide running example. It will help you to solve problem faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `ZStack` contains your "header" (consisting of a `VStack` at top level) and a `List`. Then you are applying top padding to the `List`, so that it is below the header.

I would suggest just using a `VStack` instead of a `ZStack`:

```swift
NavigationView {

    // GeometryReader not needed

    VStack(spacing: 0) { // replaces ZStack
        VStack (spacing: 24) {
            HStack (spacing: 14) {
                // content as before
            }
            ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                // content as before
            }
        }
        List {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                // content as before
            }
        }
        // no top padding needed
    }
}
```

BTW, your header section includes a `ScrollView` that contains a `ScrollViewReader`. I think it should be the `ScrollViewReader` that contains the `ScrollView`, see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader).

Comment: that just solved the problem. Ty for your precious help